# Yodlee REST API authenticate/login​ returns oauth_error_problem=invalid_url_access&oauth_error_code=418

Tags: rest, yodlee

Following the [introduction tutorial](http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Quickstart/Aggregation_REST_Quick_Start_Guide) I am trying to access

`https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0/authenticate/login​` over `POST` with `login`, `password` and `cobSessionToken` but I get the following:

```
oauth_error_problem=invalid_url_access&oauth_error_code=418
```

Any clue?

[image]

Comment: Additional evidence is that I can login from the [test drive interface](https://devnow.yodlee.com/testdrive/index.php). http://cl.ly/image/0P0h2G381q2m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try check there is no special character after '/' in 'v1.0/authenticate' or at the end of 'authenticate/login'?

Comment: Thanks, I just typed the url by hand and now it works. 

Unfortunately I am getting now "Invalid cobrand conversation credential". My cobSessionToken is definitely correct, I just called the colLogin and paste it over. What could be the issue?

Comment: I saw this comment after posting answer to your question(which is same), please refer the same.